# xampp browscap.ini is present but still get_browser() giving strange values

Tags: php, browser, xampp, browscap

**Before saying that its a duplicate please read on**, I have done my homework properly :)
I have checked the other posts but nothing helped :(

---

Here are the things that i have **already** taken care of:

**1.** Downloaded **updated copy of php_browscap.ini** from http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/     (used the '**use only with PHP**' version ofcourse)
**2.** tried  php_browscap.ini,lite_php_browscap.ini and full_php_browscap.ini
**3.** edited the php.ini file to

```
[browscap]
;http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\full_php_browscap.ini"
```

**4.** confirmed that i have changed the correct php.ini file by checking **php_info()**

**5.** and yes **removed** that **;** from ';browscap = .....'

**6. restated the xampp server**

**7.** tried checking the any file access error using "**Process Monitor**"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/loi8p0fkykzcndr/process_monitor.png

But still getting the strange values

```
Array ( [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§ [browser_name_pattern] => * [comment] => Default Browser [browser] => Default Browser [version] => 0.0 [majorver] => 0 [minorver] => 0 [platform] => unknown [platform_version] => unknown [platform_description] => unknown [alpha] => [beta] => [win16] => [win32] => [win64] => [frames] => [iframes] => [tables] => [cookies] => [backgroundsounds] => [javascript] => [vbscript] => [javaapplets] => [activexcontrols] => [ismobiledevice] => [issyndicationreader] => [crawler] => [cssversion] => 0 [aolversion] => 0 [device_name] => unknown [device_maker] => unknown [renderingengine_name] => unknown [renderingengine_version] => unknown [renderingengine_description] => unknown )
```

**Please help me, I tried a lot spending hours reading the answers posted here, tried to find a solution on google, saw videos of NewBoston**

Comment: why isn't anybody answering???

Answer (score 0):

```
// Loads the class
require 'path/to/Browscap.php';
// Creates a new Browscap object (loads or creates the cache)
$bc = new Browscap('path/to/the/cache/dir');
// Gets information about the current browser's user agent
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();    
// Output the result
echo '<pre>'; // some formatting issues ;)
print_r($current_browser);
```

We are going to obviate the last section under the comment ‘Output the result’ so your      code should look like this…

```
 // Loads the class
require 'path/to/Browscap.php';
 // Creates a new Browscap object (loads or creates the cache)
  $bc = new Browscap('path/to/the/cache/dir');
 // Gets information about the current browser's user agent
 $current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();
```

Comment: where do i get the browscap.php file from? The browscap.ini file is available not the .php file.